# sqlalchemy Base Class raises "use of property on an old style class" error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Wondering if **Base** in sqlalchemy inherits from **Object**. See detail below.

Currently using Python3 and SQLAlchemy 0.8

In my Project, I'd declared a new style class with (object) and I'd gone ahead and used "Property" to define properties in my class. The class was working okay "Sample code below"

```
class LoadFile(object):

    def _set_year(self, value): 
        '''set the year'''    
        value = value[6:10]
        if valid_integer(value) != True:
            raise Exception ("File Name Error: The year value should be a numeral")
        self._year = value
    def _get_year(self):
        '''get the year'''
        return self._year

    year = property(_get_year, _set_year)
```

As my project is growing, I've gotten around to using SQLAlchemy and ran the class, it threw the error

```
class LoadFile(object):
    __tablename__ = "load_file"
    id = Column(Integer(10), primary_key = True)
    file_name = Column(String(250), nullable = False, unique = True)
    file_path = Column(String(500), nullable = False)
    date_submitted = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
    submitted_by = Column(String, nullable = False)

    def _set_year(self, value): 
        '''set the year'''    
        value = value[6:10]
        if valid_integer(value) != True:
            raise Exception ("File Name Error: The year value should be a numeral")
        self._year = value
    def _get_year(self):
        '''get the year'''
        return self._year

    year = property(_get_year, _set_year)
```

The error it threw was:

```
AttributeError: 'LoadFile' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1369, in add
raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__main__.LoadFile' is not mapped
```

So I noticed that I wasn't inheriting from "**Base**" so I changed my class to:

```
class LoadFile(Base):
```

With that, sqlalchemy worked okay and the table was created successfully. However, I now notice that I get a warning on eclipse stating

```
Use of "property" on an old style class"
```

So am wondering, doesn't **Base** inherit from Object? Thought I'd read earlier that it does. Else, why am I getting this "warning" now. I know I can ignore it but just wanted to find out the exact reason and maybe how to correct it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I got around using decorators as seen below. This way, the above "Warning" disappears

```
@property
def year(self):
    '''get the year'''
    return self._year
@year.setter
def year(self, value): 
    '''set the year'''
    if valid_integer(value) != True:
        raise Exception ("File Name Error: The year value should be a numeral")
    self._year = value
```

So that takes care of the warning. But I still don't understand why the previous method had the warning.... Also, am not very sure which is the best method to use the decorator or the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Old-style classes do not exist in Python 3, so the warning is bogus. Check Preferences and Project Properties in Eclipse, maybe there is a reference to Python 2.x.

Comment: They actually do exist for backward compatibility hence the warning and not a "Stop Error". Anyways, I've confirmed and my python interpreter in Eclipse is set to __"/usr/bin/python3.2mu"__ and am pretty sure am using python3.2

Comment: @lukik No, they exist in Python 2.x for backwards compatibility. In Python 3.x `class C: pass` is equivalent to `class C(object): pass`